# What's the difference between an argument and a parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

I've found that a lot of developers use arguments and parameters interchangeably and it can sometimes be confusing. I'm hoping to learn the exact difference between the two.

Comment: parameter is what you define the function to accept, argument is the data you pass in as a parameter. this isn't really a stack overflow question though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters are the aliases for the values that will be passed to the function. The arguments are the actual values.

```
var foo = function( a, b, c ) {}; // a, b, and c are the parameters

foo( 1, 2, 3 ); // 1, 2, and 3 are the arguments
```